# Customise a "steps" js to refresh to current step and direct step URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some js (show/hide pretty standard I guess):

```
<script>
    function showTransactions(transactions){
        $('.steps').hide()
        $('#' + transactions).show();
    }
</script>
```

and some html:

```
<p><a href="#"onClick="showTransactions('hidden3');return false;">Edit</a></p>
<div id="hidden3" class="steps" style="display: none;">
```

Now this works great when I click the link, it shows it. Easy. How can I get the js to refresh to the current step? I have steps hidden1, hidden2, hidden3, and hidden4. The default starting position is hidden1 so on refresh it will display hidden1 instead of hidden3 if that's where you were on refresh.

Also, I need to direct users to a specific step on some instances via a url link. I tried page_url#hidden4 but that doesn't work. I need to be able to tell it to display hidden4 in that link instead of the default first step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two main things are wrong with your code:

- You do not hook your jQuery code to the "document ready" event. Not doing this will (potentially) cause it to run before the document is fully loaded, which is undesirable most of the time.
- You're using `onclick` inline JavaScript. Don't do that. That's not the way JavaScript/HTML integration is written anymore. jQuery has event handlers to catch click events for you. Always keep HTML and JavaScript 100% separate.

CSS:

```
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
<p><a class="reveal" href="#hidden3">Edit</a></p>
<div id="hidden3" class="hidden step">
```

JavaScript

```
// $() is short for $(document).ready()
$(function () {
    // hide all the steps on document load
    $("div.step").addClass("hidden");

    // show the one step that is identified by the current hash (if any)
    $(document.location.hash).removeClass("hidden");

    $("a.reveal").click(function (event) {
        var idToReveal = $(this).attr("href");

        // store the ID to show in the URL for bookmarking
        document.location.hash = idToReveal;

        // hide every step that is currently visible
        $("div.step").not(".hidden").addClass("hidden");

        // reveal the next div (as identified by the current link's href)
        $(idToReveal).removeClass("hidden");

        // prevent the default click behavior (i.e. prevent navigation)
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The above makes use of the fact that the `document.location.hash`, a page-internal `<a href>` and [jQuery's ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) all use the same syntax.

As long as you just want to transport a single bit of information in the hash, this is all you need.

Comment: This works almost perfect. Two issues: I had a default before (hidden1) but no longer see how to do that with your code and 2)if you're using the hash url, it will never close that block. For example, /page_url behaves normally with every link opening it's corresponding div and hiding the rest but /page_url#hidden3 will keep #hidden3 open no matter what. It will open and close the other steps, but #hidden3 will always remain open.

Comment: Also, I am very concerned with _"You're using onclick inline JavaScript. Don't do that. That's not the way JavaScript/HTML integration is written anymore. jQuery has event handlers to catch click events for you. Always keep HTML and JavaScript 100% separate."_ Is that really real? Or just preference? I've been inlining onSubmit, onClick, etc for a while and if this is wrong now I am in trouble.

Comment: @RKS Yes, that's real. Nobody does that anymore, and you should not write new code doing that *especially* when you're working with a library like jQuery. -- The issue that the initial `<div>` stays open no matter what was due to an error in my code. It's fixed. See [the diff](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11214692/revisions) to find out what was wrong. -- Regarding showing the default, here's a hint: Use jQuery's `.first()` to show the default first `<div>` when `hash` is not set. You'll figure out the rest, it's not difficult.

Comment: Thanks. I just gave you like 215 reputation for that.

Comment: @RKS: I hate to be pedantic, but you did not even up-vote my answer. ;)

Comment: That's because after I got done upvoting all your other stuff I got a warning that I only had five more votes left today. I can always go and unvote that 20pt question though and upvote this one...

Comment: Did you happen to test this in IE? I haven't been able to get it to work at all in any version of IE.

Comment: @RKS No, I haven't. Can you set a breakpoint in the debugger and figure out what's different in IE?

Comment: I'm still giving it a go here but I've been trying to debug using every single debug tool for IE including the developer tools. It isn't looking conclusive, but it appears it never gets past $("div.step").addClass("hidden");
 Everything gets the hidden class and there is no hash and no removeClass on any of the reveal links.

Comment: Can't find out the issue. Maybe you can see what I'm doing wrong with [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QY2Vc/)

Answer (score 0):

use cookies or localstorage to set the "state" of your wizard

```
localStorage.Step=2;
```

[Cookies (om nom nom)](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp)
[HTML LocalStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: That sounds fine and dandy. What would be the URL then to access a specific step? Like redirecting to hidden3?

Comment: well, if youre talking about when someone hits f5, then a simple $(document).ready( function(){ showTransactions(localStorage.Step);}); should do the trick

Comment: I think I understand what you're talking about as for the page refresh, but by URL what I mean is that I want to be able to provide an anchor on a separate page like <a href="/page_url#hidden3"> and this link will open this document and have hidden3 displayed.